# API call to my Symfony 5 app with debug mode disabled returns CORS error

Tags: php, api, symfony, nginx, cors

I have this problem with my Symfony 5 app which serves as my API. I am making requests to my Symfony app from another app on the same domain and different subdomain.

Everything is fine when debug mode is set to true `APP_DEBUG = 1` in my Symfony app. However if I disable debug mode `APP_DEBUG = 0`, then my requests from the other app cause CORS errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.mamacita365.com/api/getmeals' 
from origin 'https://app.mamacita365.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I am using `nelmio/cors-bundle` - here's `nelmio_cors.yaml`:

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_credentials: true
        allow_origin: ['https://api.mamacita365.com', 'https://app.mamacita365.com']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
        expose_headers: ['Link']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/': null
```

Here's `.env.local.php`:

```
<?php

// This file was generated by running "composer dump-env prod"

return array (
  'APP_ENV' => 'prod',
  'APP_DEBUG' => 0, // if equals 0 then CORS error, if equals 1 then OK
  // ...
);
```

Comment: allow_origin must be a list of regular expressions matching allowed origins. Remember to use ^ and $ to clearly define the boundaries of the regex. (cf doc)

Comment: I changed that but it had no effect. DEV is working, but PROD still has issues with CORS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the cache manually (`/var/cache/prod` folder) or via command `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: This worked. I have also changed the `allow_origin` to a regex-based value